# loading multiple .mat files in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-load

I have 110 files named time1.mat, time2.mat ..., time110.mat. I want to load these matrices into the MATLAB workspace.

I have always used `load -'ASCII' matrix.mat` to load an ASCII matrix file in the current folder.

So I tried doing

```
for i=1:10 
    filename=strcat('time',int2str(i),'.mat');
    load -'ASCII' filename
end
```

But I am getting a MATLAB error as

```
??? Error using ==> load
    Unable to read file filename: No such file or directory.
�
```

Of course the string `filename` seems to be evaluated correctly by MATLAB as `time1.mat`. in the first iteration where it crashes at the load line.

Any suggestions how I should do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `load(filename, '-ascii')`